# Exchange Advanced tab missing

Tags: active-directory, exchange

In Active Directory, if I go to a user properties, I see this:

> [image: bad]

My issue is that the Exchange Advanced tab is missing. My coworkers have this
tab, example:

> [image: good]

Online I have seen some people suggest choosing View, Advanced Features. However
when I use this option, it only adds these tabs:

- Object
- Published Certificates
- Security

and not Exchange Advanced.

Comment: Hi, it's been a long time, is there any update? If the behind information is helpful to you, you could mark the best answer. Have a nice day:-)

Answer (score 3):

The Exchange-specific settings are an add-on to Active Directory Users and Computers which only appear when Exchange Management Tools are installed on the machine.

However, this is quite old stuff: Exchange management used to be done this way back in Exchange 2003 times; since Exchange 2007, Exchange has its own management tools and integration with ADUC is not used anymore.

Comment: You can view **ALL** Active Directory attributes, including Exchange-specific ones, in the "Attribute Editor" tab; they are still stored in AD, as they have always been. But actual Exchange management is not performed from ADUC anymore.

Comment: I think I figured it out - using the Active Directory Admin Center http://woshub.com/active-directory-attribute-editor

Answer (score 1):

The `Exchange Advanced` tab was available in Exchange 2000/2003, but the later versions don't use this tool any more.
Here is a similar thread for your reference: **[Exchange Advance tab in AD for Exchange 2013](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/be690ad6-5936-4863-8ead-5ad14fc6fb0c/exchange-advance-tab-in-ad-for-exchange-2013?forum=exchangesvrgeneral)**